# How to find all rows basing on value for Main Customer ID in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am struggling with one excel case where I need to find all rows where some value appears at least once in another Column (called Reason) - for one unique Customer ID.

[image]

So in this case I need to put a flag "Y" in Column K if for a Main Customer ID there is "CAMBIO DOMICILIO" in Column H (Reason). But I need to show all rows having this Main Customer ID: the one having
"CAMBIO DOMICILIO" and these with blanks in Column H. All needs to have same Main Customer ID.

Can you please help me out?

Thank you in advance,
Pawel

Comment: When you say `Main Customer ID` do you mean `ID_1` (per the screenshot) ?

Comment: I mean Main Customer ID in Column J

Comment: Sure, didn't notice that

Comment: In `K3` you can try `=SUMPRODUCT(--($H:$H="CAMBIO DOMICILIO"),--($J:$J=$B3))` and copy down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(J:J,J2,H:H,"CAMBIO DOMICILIO"),"Y","")
```

[image]